# Putting a password to a user in PhpMyAdmin in Wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

How do you change the password for the root user in phpMyAdmin on WAMP server? because I'm locked out of phpMyAdmin, after changing the password incorrectly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

my config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin folder.
Change username and password to the one you have set for your database.

```
    <?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'enter_username_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'enter_password_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Comment: For later versions it can also be called config.sample.inc.php

Comment: I do not have a username or password line in my config.inc file

Answer (score 14):

There is a file called config.inc.php in the phpmyadmin folder.

The file path is C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4

**Edit The auth_type 'cookie' to 'config' or 'http'**

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

or

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

When you go to the phpmyadmin site then you will be asked for the username and password.  This also secure external people from accessing your phpmyadmin application if you happen to have your web server exposed to outside connections.

Comment: Duganets solution blocks phpmyadmin permanently and not even root user will be able to access. But the solution given by brianb & suchetan is really wonderful.

Answer (score 8):

Get back to the **default** setting by following this step:

Instead of

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

change it to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

in your `config.inc.php` file.

Do not specify any password and put the user name as it was before, which means `root`.

E.g.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

This worked for me after i had edited my `config.inc.php` file.

Answer (score 5):

i have some problems with it, and fixed it my using another config variable

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
instead
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

may be it will helpfull ot someone

Answer (score 2):

Search your installation of PhpMyAdmin for a file called Documentation.txt. This describes how to create a file called config.inc.php and how you can configure the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like phpmyadmin's username and password are stored elsewhere ( probably in a custom-defined config file ) in WAMP or there is some additional hashing or ... involved in the process.

So to change currently used default 'config'-file-based password you can browse "`<host>/phpmyadmin/user_password.php`" using your browser. You'll be prompted to enter your mysql credentials and then you can use the displayed form to change the stored password for the user you logged into previously.

Answer (score 0):

if didn't find any password use on command line mysql -u root -p
it will ask password it will be default password of you type at startup of installation.
It will be your password for log in of phpmyadmin