# phpMyAdmin - can't connect - invalid setings - ever since I added a root password - locked out

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, root

I run XAMPP,
a few days back i had set up a password for the root password through phpmyadmin
I am not able to access phpMyAdmin ever since that moment

I followed help on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498343/putting-a-password-to-a-user-in-phpmyadmin-in-wamp) but everything seems fine there (in config.inc.php). I even tried unistalling xampp fully, restarting windows and then reinstalling xampp, but still pointing to localhost/phpmyadmin I get the following error

```
MySQL said: 
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given
by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I Also tried to reset root password through mysqld.bat as given on mysql's website help but to no avail

Please Help!
Here's a screenshot describing the situation:
[image]

Comment: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1224  try this website might help you

Comment: sudo service mysql stop

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Go inside your phpMyAdmin directory inside XAMPP installation folder. There will be a file called config.inc.php. Inside that file, find this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

you must make sure that this field has your mysql root password (the one that you set).

Comment: i did that too, still nothing happened

Comment: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1224 

This site might help you, why dont you try it for more details

Comment: I don't set password but have this probmel

Comment: If this isn't work clear the cache of your browser and try. If not try try ip to login instead of "localhost"

Answer (score 18):

PHPMYADMIN - Cannot connect: invalid settings.

I also faced similar issue but now I found a fix.

**For wamp server:**

IN: C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadminVERSION\config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = false;
```

**For xampp server:**

because of xampp server had the following settings.

C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // which is default setting in xampp server

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your password';//type your password you have changed
```

Comment: +1. `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;` this fixed my problem for xaamp. I could not login even after I changed the password for the password field.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with my WAMP server, but, I don;t have the line you specified in the config.inc file...

Comment: It should be there, anyhow try to search that specific file name as given below. "config.inc.php"

Comment: Not working in my case :(

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem not being able to access phpmyadmin on a testing server after changing the root password.  I tried everything mentioned above, including advice from other forums, using all kinds of variations to the config files.  THEN I remembered that Google Chrome has some issues working with a testing server.  The reason is that Chrome has a security feature to prevent local hard drive access from a remote website - unfortunately this can cause issues in a testing environment because the server is a local hard drive.  When I tried to log in to phpmyadmin with Internet Explorer it worked fine.  I tried several tests of Chrome v IE9, and Chrome would not work under any configuration with the root password set.  I also tested Firefox it also worked fine, the issue is only with Chrome.  My advice:  if you're on a testing server make sure your config file has the correct settings as described above, but if the problem continues and you're using Chrome try a different browser.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Go to

```
http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php
```

Step 2: Set/Modify your password.

Step 3: Open C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php using a editor.

Step 4: Check the following lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';

// your_password = the password that you have set in Step 2.
```

Step 5: Make sure the following line is set to TRUE:
              $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Step 6: Save the file, Restart MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel

Step 7: Login into phpmyadmin with root & your password.

Note: If again the same error comes, check the security page:

```
http://localhost/security/index.php
```

It will say:
    The MySQL admin user root has no longer no password    SECURE
    PhpMyAdmin password login is enabled.                      SECURE

Then Restart your system, the problem will be solved.

Comment: I did everything till Step 7.

It says

_PhpMyAdmin is free accessible by network_ UNSECURE

Answer (score 4):

Apply these changes in phpmyconfig/config.inc. Type in your username and password that you have set:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']                 = 'user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']      = false;
```

This works for me.

Comment: Why should you turn off the AllowNoPassword option? It just means that you should have a password, that in our case is present.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem after executing the following command in mysql

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('blablabla') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

what I did:

> open cmd

type

> cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin mysql.exe -u root --password

after that mysql will prompt u

> Enter password:blablabla

once youre in mysql, type

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

**Note:** this time the password is left empty...

make sure in your config.inc.php the following is set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

after that I can see my phpmyadmin...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what finally worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Difference was that I was getting this error for only one database out all my   databases.
I removed the password , restarted mysql many times and still it dint work :(

And when I cleared the cache of my browser it just started working !!!

This one really screwed my mind !

Answer (score 2):

For any ubuntu users visiting this page, I was facing the same error and the issue was XAMPP (LAMPP in ubuntu) was not able to connect to mysql because another mysql service was working so my solution to this issue was

stop mysql service

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

restart lampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem using the Windows XAMPP 1.7.4 -- after setting a password for mysql, I could no longer access phpMyAdmin.  I changed the password in config.inc.php from ' ' to the new mysql password, and changed AllowNoPassword from true to false.  I still couldn't log in.

However, I saw that there is also a config.inc.php.safe file, and when I also edited the password settings in THAT file I was subsequently able to log in to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the noob too when I encountered something like this.
So... I set the passwords using the command security page gave me:
 /opt/lampp/lampp security
Then I used password xyz for all the passwords...
Then when I go to site/, it ask for a basic authentication.
But when I tried root//xyz, it does not allow me login.
So, after some digging, it turns out the xyz password was set for a default user named 'lampp'.
When I tried to login using lampp//xyz, it worked like a charm.

The issue is that they made an assumption that everyone knows to use lampp//rootpw as their login  o.O
And... that is a basic auth for the directory! not pw for phpmyadmin or pw for mysql...

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to your Xampp Root folder

For Ex : **C:xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

2) In that find  the following :

```
$cfg['servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

3) Here enter which password you set.

Ex : `$cfg['servers'][$i]['password'] = '1234';`

4) Then Save it and Restart your Xamp server.

Answer (score 0):

> This works for me:
>
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
>
> ```
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'secret';
> ```

Edit: Before you got this error it is most likely that from phpmyadmin->Users you have added password for the **root** user. 
In my case that was "secret" so the above primer works for me BUT for you will work this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Enter the password for root you have added before you got this error';
```

Answer (score 0):

For AMPPS, I have to add this is my `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Note: In Ubuntu, I had to locate where the file is and I used `locate config.inc.php`

This answer is only meant for local, development purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. The best way to solve is to go to computer>Local disk>xampp. Right click on the xampp folder and restore it to a previous date that worked. It worked perfectly for me.