# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) When changing user in db

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I just tried changig the username of root in my db, in phpmyadmin in xampp. And when I did I didnt get in to phpmyadmin anymore and I got this error when I tried:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Uppkoppling för kontrollanvändare enligt din konfiguration misslyckades.
(connection for controlluser according to your konfiguration failed)

phpMyAdmin försökte skapa en förbindelse till MySQL-servern, men servern nekade uppkopplingen. Kontrollera värd, användarnamn och lösenord i din konfiguration och förvissa dig om att de stämmer överens med informationen från administratören av MySQL-servern.
(phpmyAdmin tried to create a connection to MySQL-server but the server denied the connection. Controll the host, username and password in your configuratuon and make sure that they are the same as the information from the administratior of the MySQL-server.)

Please, how can I solved this? Without having to reinstall? Have a lot of databases there I dont want to loose :(.

Comment: Please show your connect file

Comment: What connect file? Do you know the name of it and where to find it?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276538/phpmyadmin-cant-connect-invalid-setings-ever-since-i-added-a-root-passwor)

Comment: I go throu xampp just on the admin button for mySQL

Comment: Will check it Vahan! I only found when they had root still as username.

Comment: The answere there will not work for me, dont have a password. I tried writing in the username I changed to, then I got in, there where errors in myphpadmin and all my databases where gone.

Comment: Yes I use xampp and phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I think I might have been a little bit tired yesterday. I changed the username in config.inc.php and I didnt get in, I realized that I hadent changed them all, found one on localhost and got in, then I saw that aperently the privliges didin't follow with when I changed the username, therefore the access was denied. So now I have changed the privliges and it works just fine! *phju* Thanks for trying to help and yes Vahan, then the question you linked was almost the same!