# XAMPP phpMyAdmin won't start after installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I just installed the newest version of XAMPP in order to move to the newest version of PHP, 7.something, but when I navigate to http://localhost/dashboard/ and try to enter phpMyAdmin, I get the following error:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

What can I do about it so that I can access phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Did you installed in a new direction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Did you installed New Xampp in new Path?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276538/phpmyadmin-cant-connect-invalid-setings-ever-since-i-added-a-root-passwor

Comment: No, farshid. I installed it in the same path but backed up the original installation before that. Then I moved the htdocs and the data folder back to the new installation and everything works fine, except that I get this error and cannot access phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thank you, leonida. This solved my problem. I had to enter password in:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

file: config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword';
```