# Not able to connect ti phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I Uninstalled XAMPP1.6 and then installed XAMPP3.2.2 apache and other working fine but getting issue with phpmyadmin i'm not able to login into PMA Getting below error[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276538/phpmyadmin-cant-connect-invalid-setings-ever-since-i-added-a-root-passwor) this but still same issue coming .

Comment: Have you download this phpmyadmin from their site

Comment: No I installed XAMPP 3.2.2 before that uninstalled old one (XAMPP1.6) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether your MySQL instance is the current one bundled with the new version or still the old one. May be your xxamp is still referencing the old MySQL. Make sure your old MySQL was killed before you install new version of XXAMP.

Comment: How can i check this , i changed Mysql refering path to latest one through run -> regedit -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> SERVICES ->MYSQL-> Image path

Comment: If you install a new XXAMP while MySQL service is not killed, XXAMP will use the old configuration. What does your XXAMP tell you when you start MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180893/mysql-said-cannot-connect-invalid-settings-xampp

Comment: I changed` $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';` in config file not i'm able to login into PMA but not able to create database  showing **No Privileges**