# No Privileges to create database in MYSQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm facing issue with PMA Login [see error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435364/not-able-to-connect-ti-phpmyadmin/40435388?noredirect=1#comment68118701_40435388) for that i changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = ''` before it was `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'` , now i'm able to login but now **No Privileges** issue coming .

Please help me to solve this issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Come back name user for root anything else.

Comment: then getting this [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435364/not-able-to-connect-ti-phpmyadmin/40435388?noredirect=1#comment68118701_40435388)